# The += operator with nullable types in C#

Tags: c#, operators, nullable

In C#, if I write

```
int? x = null;
x += x ?? 1
```

I would expect this to be equivalent to:

```
int? x = null;
x = x + x ?? 1
```

And thus in the first example, `x` would contain `1` as in the second example. But it doesn't, it contains null. The += operator doesn't seem to work on nullable types when they haven't been assigned. Why should this be the case?

**Edit**: As pointed out, it's because `null + 1 = null` and operator precedence. In my defence, I think this line in the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) is ambiguous!:

> The predefined unary and binary operators and any user-defined
>   operators that exist for value types may also be used by nullable
>   types. These operators produce a null value if *[either of]* the
>   operands are null; otherwise, the operator uses the contained value to
>   calculate the result.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here is the difference between the two statements:

```
x += x ?? 1
x = (x + x) ?? 1
```

The second isn't what you were expecting.

Here's a breakdown of them both:

```
x += x ?? 1
x += null ?? 1
x += 1
x = x + 1
x = null + 1
x = null

x = x + x ?? 1
x = null + null ?? 1
x = null ?? 1
x = 1
```

Comment: +1 Ah, operator precedence, my ancient foe. You strike again!

Comment: Doesn't `??` have precedence over `+`? (@Servy's answer)

Comment: Ah, I failed to appreciate that null + 1 = null. Missed this line in the MSDN: 

The predefined unary and binary operators and any user-defined operators that exist for value types may also be used by nullable types. These operators produce a null value if the operands are null; otherwise, the operator uses the contained value to calculate the result.